# devolver columna segun valor de una fila en pandas

Tags: python, pandas, bucle-for

tengo que revisar el valor de unas 200 columnas de un dataframe, tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
  for i in df.columns:
    if len(df[df[i].str.contains('Texto')])>0:
        print(i)
```

el codigo me funciona bien y me devuelve el nombre de la columna que es lo deseado, hay alguna otra forma de hacerle que sea mas eficiente?

PD: para mejorar su velocidad la busqueda la realizo solo en la ultima fila, que es la que contiene los datos que deseo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nota: Tu código no funciona, Pandas dice que el valor de verdad de una serie es ambigua y que uses ciertos métodos. Aun así, te ofresco el modo más optimizado que logre hacer.

---

Para empezar, los bucles for deben ser tu ultimo recurso cuando usas Pandas. Eso se debe a que sus funciones están hechas en C, que es más rapido que Python.
Siguiendo ese principio y otros que mencionaré luego, obtenemos esta solución de una sola linea:

```
df.columns.to_series()[df.iloc[-1].str.startswith("Texto")]
```

A continuación, una explicación paso a paso:

1. Obtenemos las columnas y el indice obtenido lo convertimos a una serie para poder trabajarlo mejor en un futuro.
2. Dentro de los corchetes, le aplicamos una serie de booleanos.
3. Esa serie la obtenemos obteniendo la ultima fila (ya que dices que es el unico caso importante) y aplicamos `.str.startswith("Texto")`. Esto resultará en una serie donde cada valor corresponde a una respectiva columna y es true cuando el valor en dicha fila comienza con "Texto".
   df.iloc nos permite acceder a un valor, fila o columna a partir de su posicion.

###### Demo

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["1"]*199 + ["Texto del mundo"]])
print(df.columns.to_series()[df.iloc[-1].str.startswith("Texto")])
```

###### Produce

```
199    199
dtype: int64
```

Comment: le modifique otra vez, antes usaba lo que ahora con la funcion len y me funciona, le modifique sin el len y me funciono un momento, no se por que, he probado su codigo y todo bien, pero para que devuelva solo el nombre de la columna y sin el dtype como seria?? por cierto, muchas gracias por su respuesta

Comment: De nada! Podés usar .iloc[0] en el resultado. eso te devolverá la primera fila de la serie.